# is there a way to remove the first line from a StreamReader

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

i have a streamreader which loads up a csvfile, the issue is that there is one extra row at the top of the data that i want to ignore.

I am using the [CSVReader project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) which is great but

```
 csv.GetFieldHeaders();
```

always looks at the first row.  Instead of going into the CSVReader source code and changing it, i thought it might be easier if i can "strip" out this first row from the streamreader itself before injecting it into the csvReader.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just read a line from the SR before you pass it to the CSVReader constructor.  For example:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("data.csv")) {
    sr.ReadLine();
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(sr, true)) {
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would just be to call `ReadLine()` yourself before you pass the reader on to the `CSVReader`.

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader` is a virtual class, so you could create an inherited class that delegates all important functionality to some underlying `StreamReader`, with the exception that it skips the first line of text (or you could inherit from the `TextReader` type). If the `CSVReader` takes the `StreamReader` or `TextReader` as an argument, this should work fine.